# How to access SMS Message threads from Windows phone programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I want to access all messages on a windows phone & take the back up of it or make a copy of it on PC / Phone.

I searched for this but couldn't get this on internet.

Is there any API available for achieving this.

This is for Windows Phone OS 7.5 Mango only.

Comment: As of now we don't have answer for this & If you are also looking for same then PLEAS VOTE : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8987979/368472

Comment: how does this app work ? http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/mytexttwister/0db2a471-6f36-4e7f-8e95-acfff7f33f44

Comment: @GauravShah - The app can't access Message Thread History, It can only send new sms! We are looking for accessing a previously composed messages.

Comment: The preview shows threaded view of messages so I thought it shows received too...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no API  available for this.

But yesterday I've found this:
http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform

You can vote there:) Page is connected with apphub forum.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did vote there! But can't there be any way to access Messages (SMS) because its possible in Android OS

Comment: At the moment you can only create sms by "launcher"

Comment: Check out this MS page for more information.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394005(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no API which allows you to access the user's SMS. Though there is a way to launch the Messaging application with the "Body" and "To" filed programmatically filled in.

The [Microsoft.Phone.Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) provide you with various classes which allow your application to launch various inbuilt application in windows phone such as contacts application, sms application, email application, camera application, search application etc.

The [SMSComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.smscomposetask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) class is what you need to launch the messaging application.

Comment: Can SmsComposeTask Class or Classes be able to get message in inbox (i.e. Stored SMS) through properties like Body & To which infact has GET behavior

Comment: nope! It is only for the 'new message' and not the existing ones.

Comment: Okay fine. If I'm not wrong its for sending a new message, so whenever I send a message can I access at that point of time to its body & get the content & store it somewhere by some background app ?? Can this be implemented ??

Comment: You mean when the user sends an SMS or you (as the programmer send the sms?). If its the later then its your app, you can access the details as you are deciding what should be sent. If its the earlier then sorry there isn't a way for you to do that!