# How can I read the incoming sms in my Windows Phone 7 application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access SMS Message threads from Windows phone programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987858/how-to-access-sms-message-threads-from-windows-phone-programmatically)

I'm try to access the incoming sms in my application which will be running in behind and check for certain text in the sms and perform the task if the text matches the format as specified in application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access SMS Message threads from Windows phone programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8987858/50447)

Comment: how does this app work http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/mytexttwister/0db2a471-6f36-4e7f-8e95-acfff7f33f44

Answer (score 1):

3rd party developers are not allowed access to Text messages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible in current API.