# how to track sent message event in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way in windows phone to track sent message event? i mean to say that whenever a message is sent then a function of my application execute
all i want is to execute a function whenever sent message button of windows phone is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the message launcher (I don't remember the exact name), it'll open this screen and you have the event (something like application deactivated) and once the user sends the message, the screen should close and come back to your app (again another event is available at that point, activated). 
So you'll have to play with the events to do something you like, IIRC there is no call back when the message button is clicked.

Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) with the lifecycle of apps

Answer (score 0):

There is no API that notifies you if a message was sent (at least no open API). A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987858/how-to-access-sms-message-threads-from-windows-phone-programmatically).